# e.preventdefault(); not working

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I'm having real trouble getting `e.preventDefault();` to work.

Here is my code

```
$('#ListSnapshot a').live('click', function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr('href') +' #WebPartWPQ2 .ms-listviewtable';
    $('#ListSnapshot').load(url);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong, I can see the load function work but then the page redirects to the clicked link which I need to prevent.

I have also tried moving `e.preventDefault();` to the top of the function, to no avail.

Comment: I have a feeling there's something else going on here, because `preventDefault` *should* be working. Can we see the markup / other code?

Comment: Like J-P has said, it looks like there's something else going on here at it should work as expected. Can you provide the HTML for #ListSnapshot and it's children?

Comment: I removed the answer from your question, you should post it as answer when the question is open again.

Comment: I know this is closed, but I found it on Google just like many others will when they have this problem. My problem was simply that another click event was being binded to the element at a later point in the script, overwriting the existing click event and causing e.preventDefault() to fail. Hope that helps someone else that runs into this problem.

Comment: I also know this is closed but found it on Google. Had the same issue but the root cause turned out to be that I had over written the file which called the javascript on the page!

Comment: Same googling issue here, try https://stackoverflow.com/a/70264343/7089048

Answer (score 54):

I had a similar problem, in which `e.preventDefault()` would work on some cases, but not on others. It showed no errors, and using `try-catch` was not displaying the `catch alert`.
Adding `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` did the trick, in case it helps anyone (big thanks to wcpro)

Comment: Thanks, worked well. This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 13):

i think you may have the following scenerio... at least, this will reproduce the error

you may have an event higher up that is setup for the hover event, that event may be using bind, and even if you call e.preventdefault it will still call the bind first, so you may need to make the one higher up use live instead of bind.  then it should work as expected.  check this sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/rodmjay/mnkq3/

```
$('div').bind ('click', function(){ // <-- switch this to live and you will see different behavior

    alert('div click');

});

$('a').live('click', function(e){


    alert('a click');

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();


});
```

Comment: This can happen to delete link for Rails, as Rails will add events which you might not be aware.

Comment: That's was my issue, thanks to helped me :)

Comment: .live() has been removed in jQuery 1.9; use on() instead.

Answer (score 6):

The code you've provided should definitely be working ([working example](http://jsbin.com/itono4/edit)). There's got to be another issue with your code.

Try placing an alert inside your event handler to make sure that it fires *at all*. It's possible that your `#ListSnapshot a` isn't finding anything.

If something else is wrong inside your handler, that causes an exception, that could prevent the javascript from executing all the way to the `preventDefault` call. I don't see what that could be in the code you've provided, tho.

Comment: I think this is probably the answer. `try..catch` should help.

Comment: Ive edited the question because i wasnt sure how to add a reply, and could not fit it all in this box.
Thanks
Again

Comment: @Gary: You did the best thing -- Editing your question with detail and then commenting to let others know to review your edited question is the appropriate way to handle this. That being said, given that the alert does show, I'm not sure what the issue is. It's not an exception as I had suspected :-(

Answer (score 3):

Try returning `false`. `live` will not always work the same way as `bind` works. check jquery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: Thanks, im afraid ive tried that but still no luck. 

Thanks Again
Gary

Comment: I'm using .on() and return false worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I think @David Hedlund's answer is correct, there must be an exception happening. When I write event handlers I use a `try...catch` block to make sure that the default action doesn't happen. Try this:

```
$('#ListSnapshot a').live('click', function(e){
    try {
        var url = $(this).attr('href') +' #WebPartWPQ2 .ms-listviewtable';
        $('#ListSnapshot').load(url);
    } catch(ex) {
        alert('An error occurred and I need to write some code to handle this!');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

That way, since `e.preventDefault();` is outside the `try` block, even if an error occurs, `e.preventDefault();` will still be called.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wrapping the event handler in `$(document).ready(...)` first? Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

e.preventDefault() should execute before the other lines of code in the handler.

```
$('#ListSnapshot a').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href') +' #WebPartWPQ2 .ms-listviewtable';
    $('#ListSnapshot').load(url);
});
```

Comment: Yeah that fixed it for me in testing on the iPhone 6S Plus. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this is just the kind of moment should see what firebug logs in the console or returns as error. Something in your code is obviously preventing preventDefault() from prevent a redirect.