# Make items visible with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, preventdefault

I have this javascript code:

```
function newsOverview() {
    $(".list-news li:gt(3)").hide();
    $(".box-news .btn-1").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault;
        $(".list-news li:visible:last").nextAll(":lt(4)").fadeIn(600);
    });
};
```

I have a big list with li items. This script is showing every time 4 li items. When you clicking on the btn-1 button. But now i have a question with this script.

- Why the e.preventDefault is not working? When i clicking the button. I scrolling back to the top of the page. Why does that is not working?
- And, Is it possible. When all items are visible. That the button disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) preventDefault is not working because it's a function. 
It should be like follows:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

2) To see if all items are visible, try to use the following code:

```
if ($(".list-news li:hidden").lehgth == 0) {
   $(".box-news .btn-1").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why the e.preventDefault is not working?

You're missing the parenthesis in order to actually *call* `preventDefault`:

```
function newsOverview() {
    $(".list-news li:gt(3)").hide();
    $(".box-news .btn-1").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // don't forget those
        $(".list-news li:visible:last").nextAll(":lt(4)").fadeIn(600);
    });
};
```

> And, Is it possible. When all items are visible. That the button disappears.

My jQuery is a little bit rusty, but something like this should work:

```
function newsOverview() {
    $(".list-news li:gt(3)").hide();
    $(".box-news .btn-1").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(".list-news li:hidden").length === 0)
            $(this).hide();
        else
            $(".list-news li:visible:last").nextAll(":lt(4)").fadeIn(600);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[e.preventdefault(); not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362481/e-preventdefault-not-working)

and, you always can use "return false;" on button, i think.

Comment: This should be a comment or vote to close, not an answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer.