# how to change an anchor tag using jquery by selecting its class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this may seem really simple but am having trouble this end figuring out a way of selecting the class and changing ONLY that href.. here is the html ...

```
<a href="http://www.something" class="theclassname">LEARN MORE</a>
```

so far with javascript ...

```
$('.theclassname').click(function(){
    (change the href to www.awesome.com)
});
```

So far really appreciate alll answers on this ... I need the href to change but not go to the url that it has changed to until the user clicks once more... so far the actual code is this ...

```
$('.hrefclass').click(function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr("href", "http://www.google.org/");
    $('.kwicks').kwicks({
        maxSize: '100%',
        behavior: 'menu'
    });
});
```

however this does not appear to work .

LATEST

Ok so adding return false indeed works but also stops the kiwcks function from running ... how can i get around this ?

```
$('.hrefclassname').one("click", function() {
$('.kwicks').kwicks({
maxSize: '100%',
behavior: 'menu'
    });
    $(this).attr("href", "http://www.gooogle.org/");
return false;
});
```

LATEST LATEST

```
$('.HREFCLASSNAME').one("click", function() {
 e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr("href", "http://www.GOOGLE.org/");
$('.kwicks').kwicks({
maxSize: '100%',
behavior: 'menu'
    });

});
```

Comment: In regards to your edit, try starting the href out as being href="javascript:void(0)", that way it won't link to anything before the user clicks to change it.

Comment: still nothing , what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Just added a jsFiddle to my answer, so you can see it working in context.

Comment: yeah it toally works in your fiddle but i have no idea why it wont work with the associated code i am using when it works just fine without the link change

Comment: ok , problem is with return false is that it stops the kwicks function from completing how do i get aruond this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code (as others have mentioned) should work:

```
// notice "e" being passed to the function:
$('.HREFCLASSNAME').one("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // assuming "this" is an "<a>" tag: 
    $(this).attr("href", "http://www.GOOGLE.org/");
    $('.kwicks').kwicks({
         maxSize: '100%',
         behavior: 'menu'
    });
});
```

This should stop the "event propagation," or in other words the link should not fire.

If this the link is still firing, you may have an issue similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362481/e-preventdefault-not-working) where the event is "bubbling up" and causing the link to fire anyway. *If* this is the case (which, would indicate you haven't provided a valid html example for your specific problem,) you can stop the event from propagating by replacing `e.preventDefault()` with this:

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$(this).attr('href','www.awesome.com')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `attr()` method of jQuery to alter the links. `href` is the attribute here and the link is its value.

```js
$('.theclassname').on('click', function() {
  $(this).attr('href', 'http://google.com');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.something" class="theclassname">LEARN MORE</a>
```

Comment: the prevent default isn't working i edited the post to show my code it just goes straight to the link and when i put in the preventDefault line it does nothing

Comment: You didn't pass the parameter `e` in your code. `function (e)`

Answer (score 2):

In your function, the variable "this" contains the DOM element that you clicked on. Wrap it using jQuery using "`$(this)`", then call jQuery's [attr function](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the `href` attribute to whatever url you'd like.

Here is a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/57foqwaq/2/

Here's the example code:

```
$('.theclassname').one("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr("href", "https://www.example.com/");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an invocation to a link of `theclassname` when it is clicked, and then to show the text and URL of the link you can try this other option:

## HTML

```
<a rel='1' class="theclassname" href="option1.html">Option 1</a>
<a rel='2' class="theclassname" href="option2.html">Option 2</a>
```

## jQuery

```
$('.theclassname').one('click', function() {
   var link = $(this);
   alert (link.html());
   alert (link.attr('href'));
   alert (link.attr('rel'));

   return false;
});
```

The return false prevents the link from being followed.

Comment: jQuery's `.live` has been deprecated for a long time now

Comment: Thank you @gustavo-hoirisch for remember me that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to try:

```
$(this).attr("href", new_href);
```

And I think it might work for you.