# MUI TextField: How to prevent form from being submitted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui

I am building a form using *React* and *MUI*. I want to prevent the form from being submitted when the user presses the enter key. Normally I would do that with `e.preventDefault()`, but somehow that doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the [`TextField`](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/) component from MUI.

Here is a simple example for my form and here is

```js
function MyForm() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      /* do submit stuff here */
    }}>
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
      <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

preventDefault function in onSubmit of form, prevents the page from being reloaded, and basically you need to write another preventDefault inside of the textfield as below:

```
<TextField
   onKeyDown={e => e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden text input field:

`<input hidden type="text" />`