# How do I make my page stop refreshing after clicking submit button?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make popup window with form in it. When clicking submit, page is refreshing. How can I prevent it? My `e.preventDefault` is not working

```
modalsubmit.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  modal.classList.toggle('overlay_opened');
  profilettl.textContent = modalname.value;
  profdesc.textContent = modaldesc.value;
});
```

Comment: Can you add more details about HTML? The `modalsubmit` element? Try having a full snippet including HTML and JS

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362481/e-preventdefault-not-working) SO question! Try adding `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` [(mdn web docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've added the submit event listener to the button and not the form. Check this out and it should work.

```js
const modalsubmit = document.querySelector('form');

modalsubmit.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the e.stopPropagation() to interrupt the default behavior

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation